# Recursion in java with objects of courses and prerequisites

Tags: java, class, recursion

Good day, is there a more efficient way to do this problem with recursion than using a switch statement. In my courses class I have a recursive association of course and a prerequisite then a set the preReqs in the PreReqs class. How can I print out all of preReqs of a class when a user enter a class which has preReqs? Right now I am in the process of using a switch statement and printing each preReq individually but is there a better way to do this still using recursion?

An example out of this: If the user types that course, all of the preReqs will print out too.

```
ACS-3947 Algorithm Design
prereq: ACS-2947 Data Structures and Algorithms
ACS-2947 Data Structures and Algorithms
prereq: ACS-1904 Programming Fundamentals II
ACS-1904 Programming Fundamentals II
prereq: ACS-1903 Programming Fundamentals I
ACS-1903 Programming Fundamentals I
no prereq
```

Course class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Course
{  
    protected String courseNumber; 
    protected String courseName;
    protected Course prerequisite; 

    public Course(){
        courseNumber = courseName =  "Unknown"; 
        prerequisite= null; 
    }

    public Course (String cn, String num){
        this.courseNumber=num;
        this.courseName=cn; 
    }

    public String getCourseNumber(){
        return courseNumber;
    }
    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }
    public Course getPreReq(){
        return prerequisite;
    }

    public void setCourseNumber(String courseNumber){
        this.courseNumber=courseNumber;
    }
    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName=courseName;
    }
    public void setPreReq(Course pr){
        prerequisite =pr; 
    }

}
```

PreReq class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Prereqs 
{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

        Course nineteen03 = new Course ("Programming Fundamentals I","ACS-1903");
        Course nineteen04 = new Course ("Programming Fundamentals II"," ACS-1904");
        Course two47 = new Course ("Data Structures and Algorithms","ACS-2947 "); 
        Course three47 = new Course ("Algorithm Design","ACS-3947");
        Course two09 = new Course ("Internet Programming","ACS-2909");
        Course three09 = new Course ("Advanced Internet Programming ","ACS-3909");

        nineteen04.setPreReq(nineteen03);
        two47.setPreReq(nineteen04);
        three47.setPreReq(two47);
        two09.setPreReq(nineteen03);
        three09.setPreReq(nineteen03); 
        System.out.println("Enter course number with the format: AAA-999");
        String input = kb.next(); 

         validate(input);
    }

    public static void course(Course nineteen04, Course nineteen03,Course two47, Course three47, Course two09, Course three09, String input  ){
        Course c1 = nineteen04.getPreReq();
        Course c2 = two47.getPreReq();
        Course c3 = three47.getPreReq(); 
        Course c4 = two09.getPreReq();
        Course c5 = three09.getPreReq();

        switch (input){
            case "ACS-1904":
            System.out.println(nineteen04.getCourseName()+" "+nineteen04.getCourseNumber());
            System.out.println("preReq: " + c1.getCourseName()+ " "+ c1.getCourseNumber());

        }

    }

    public static String validate (String input)
    {   
        String arg = input;

        boolean valid = arg.length()==7;

        if (!valid){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not the correct format: AAA-999");           
        }
        valid = arg.charAt(3) == '-';  
        if(!valid) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not the correct format: AAA-999");
        }
        for(int i=0; i < 3 && valid; i++){
            valid = ((i == 3 && Character.isLetter(arg.charAt(i))));
        }

        for(int i=3; i < 3 && valid; i++){
            valid = ((i==6 && Character.isDigit(arg.charAt(i))));
        }
        return arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to do this only with recursion? or you want more efficient way?

Comment: using only recursion please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive method needs to contain a condition which terminates the recursion. Your list of courses and their prerequisites remind me of a linked list where each course points to its prerequisite. The list terminates when we reach a course that has no prerequisite. The below code is your `Course` class with the addition of a main method (imported from your `Prereqs` class) and the recursive method which I named `requirements()`. I also added method `toString()` to make the display of the list of courses and their prerequisites more "human readable". You can experiment by changing the course passed to the initial invocation of method `requirements()`.

```java
public class Course {
    protected String courseNumber;
    protected String courseName;
    protected Course prerequisite;

    public Course(){
        courseNumber = courseName =  "Unknown";
        prerequisite= null;
    }

    public Course (String cn, String num){
        this.courseNumber=num;
        this.courseName=cn;
    }

    public String getCourseNumber(){
        return courseNumber;
    }

    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }

    public Course getPreReq(){
        return prerequisite;
    }

    public void setCourseNumber(String courseNumber){
        this.courseNumber=courseNumber;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName){
        this.courseName=courseName;
    }

    public void setPreReq(Course pr){
        prerequisite =pr;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return courseNumber + " " + courseName;
    }

    private static void requirements(Course c) {
        if (c == null) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(c);
            requirements(c.getPreReq());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course nineteen03 = new Course ("Programming Fundamentals I","ACS-1903");
        Course nineteen04 = new Course ("Programming Fundamentals II"," ACS-1904");
        Course two47 = new Course ("Data Structures and Algorithms","ACS-2947 "); 
        Course three47 = new Course ("Algorithm Design","ACS-3947");
        Course two09 = new Course ("Internet Programming","ACS-2909");
        Course three09 = new Course ("Advanced Internet Programming ","ACS-3909");

        nineteen04.setPreReq(nineteen03);
        two47.setPreReq(nineteen04);
        three47.setPreReq(two47);
        two09.setPreReq(nineteen03);
        three09.setPreReq(nineteen03);

        requirements(three09);
    }
}
```

Running the above code displays the following:

```
ACS-3909 Advanced Internet Programming 
ACS-1903 Programming Fundamentals I
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, much needed. I will experiment what i can do.